# Donde colocar el input para que me muestre la informacion

Tags: php, html

Estoy realizando un formulario en el cual agrego informacion, edito y elimino. Cuando registro la informacion no hay error, pero cuando quiero ver toda la informacion registrada ahi es cuando me marca error, ya que dice que no se encuentra el valor "idDolor" y no se en que parte del formulario colocarlo, aclaro que el valor es del mismo tipo de que idPaciente, que solo guarda un numero (en la base de datos, tanto idDolor como idPaciente son llaves primarias y auto-incrementables)

Este es el error que me harroga al momento de querer ver la informacion para poder editarla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo tanto del formulario como de las funciones, ya revise varias veces el codigo de las funciones y segun yo esta bien, el problema es en el formulario, pero no se en que parte colocar el valor de "idDolor" para que funcione correctamente. Tambien aclaro que en este codigo coloque ya coloque un input donde esta el valor "idDolor" pero me sigue marcando error.

```
<div id="modalpaciente" class="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="mdltitulo">Nuevo Registro</h4>
        </div>
        <form method="post" id="paciente_form">
        <input type="hidden" id="idPaciente" name="idPaciente">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-12" for="nombrePac">Nombre</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombrePac" name="nombrePac" placeholder="" required>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-12" for="apellidoP">Apellido Paterno</label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellidoP" name="apellidoP" placeholder="" required>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-12" for="apellidoM">Apellido Materno</label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellidoM" name="apellidoM" placeholder="" required>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-12" for="edad">Edad</label>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edad" name="edad" placeholder="" required>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-12" for="Sexo_idSexo">Sexo</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <select class="form-control" id="Sexo_idSexo" name="Sexo_idSexo">
                            <option value="0">Seleccione una Opcion</option>
                            <option value="1">Masculino</option>
                            <option value="2">Femenino</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-12" for="Ocupacion_idOcupacion">Ocupacion</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <select class="form-control" id="Ocupacion_idOcupacion" name="Ocupacion_idOcupacion">
                            <option value="0">Seleccione una Opcion</option>
                            <option value="1">Estudiante</option>
                            <option value="2">Profesionista</option>
                            <option value="3">Empleado</option>
                            <option value="4">Tecnico</option>
                            <option value="5">Otro</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-12" for="telefono">Telefono</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefono" name="telefono" placeholder="" required>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-12" for="calleNumero">Calle y Numero</label>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="calleNumero" name="calleNumero" rows="3" placeholder="" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-12" for="colonia">Colonia</label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="colonia" name="colonia" placeholder="" required>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-12" for="cp">C.P</label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cp" name="cp" placeholder="" required>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-12" for="ciudad">Ciudad</label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ciudad" name="ciudad" placeholder="" required>
                        </div>
                </div> 
        <input type="hidden" id="idDolor" name="idDolor">
                <label class="col-12" for="Localizacion_idLocalizacion">Localizacion de Dolor</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <select class="form-control" id="Localizacion_idLocalizacion" name="Localizacion_idLocalizacion">
                        <option value="0">Seleccione una Opcion</option>
                        <option value="1">Ojo izquierdo</option>
                        <option value="2">Ojo derecho</option>
                        <option value="3">Ambos</option>
                        <option value="4">Ninguno</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-12" for="sintomas">Sintomas</label>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="sintomas" name="sintomas" rows="3" placeholder="" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default btn-default" type="button">Cerrar</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary"  type="submit" name="action" value="add" id="#">Guardar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Este es el codigo de las funciones:

```
<?php
 require_once("../config/conexion.php");
 require_once("../models/Paciente.php");
 $paciente = new Paciente();

  switch($_GET["op"]){

  case "listar":
     $datos = $paciente->get_paciente();
     $data = Array();
     foreach($datos as $row){
        $sub_array = array();
        $sub_array[] = $row["nombrePac"]; //Va el nombre de nuestro campo de la BD
        $sub_array[] = $row["fecha_crea"];
        $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" onClick="editar('.$row["idPaciente"].');"  id="'.$row["idPaciente"].'" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-icon"><div><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></div></button>';
        $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" onClick="eliminar('.$row["idPaciente"].');"  id="'.$row["idPaciente"].'" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-icon"><div><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></div></button>';
        $data[]=$sub_array;
     }

     $results = array(
        "sEcho"=>1,
        "iTotalRecords"=>count($data),
        "iTotalDisplayRecords"=>count($data),
        "aaData"=>$data);
     echo json_encode($results);

  break;

  case "guardaryeditar":
     $datos = $paciente->get_paciente_x_id($_POST["idPaciente"]);
     if(empty($_POST["idPaciente"])){ //Si "idPaciente" esta vacio o no tiene alguna informacion
        if(is_array($datos) == true and count($datos) == 0){ //Si la variable "datos" no me trajo ningun registro o ningun array, se realiza el insert
           $paciente->insert_paciente($_POST["nombrePac"],$_POST["apellidoP"],$_POST["apellidoM"],$_POST["edad"],
           $_POST["Sexo_idSexo"],$_POST["Ocupacion_idOcupacion"],$_POST["telefono"],$_POST["calleNumero"],$_POST["colonia"],
           $_POST["cp"],$_POST["ciudad"]); //La variable "paciente" llama a la funcion insert_paciente
        }
     }else{
        $paciente->update_paciente($_POST["idPaciente"], $_POST["nombrePac"], $_POST["apellidoP"], $_POST["apellidoM"],
        $_POST["edad"], $_POST["Sexo_idSexo"], $_POST["Ocupacion_idOcupacion"], $_POST["telefono"], $_POST["calleNumero"],
        $_POST["colonia"], $_POST["cp"], $_POST["ciudad"]);
     }

     $datos = $paciente->get_dolor_x_id($_POST["idDolor"]);
     if(empty($_POST["idDolor"])){ 
        if(is_array($datos) == true and count($datos) == 0){ 
           $paciente->insert_dolor($_POST["Localizacion_idLocalizacion"],$_POST["sintomas"]);
        }
     }else{
        $paciente->update_dolor($_POST["idDolor"], $_POST["Localizacion_idLocalizacion"], $_POST["sintomas"]);
     }
     
  break;

  case "mostrar": //Traera todos los datos y los separa en un JSON para que se puedan reutilizar
     $datos = $paciente->get_paciente_x_id($_POST["idPaciente"]);
     if(is_array($datos) == true and count($datos) > 0){
        foreach($datos as $row){
           $output["idPaciente"] = $row["idPaciente"];
           $output["nombrePac"] = $row["nombrePac"];
           $output["apellidoP"] = $row["apellidoP"];
           $output["apellidoM"] = $row["apellidoM"];
           $output["edad"] = $row["edad"];
           $output["Sexo_idSexo"] = $row["Sexo_idSexo"];
           $output["Ocupacion_idOcupacion"] = $row["Ocupacion_idOcupacion"];
           $output["telefono"] = $row["telefono"];
           $output["calleNumero"] = $row["calleNumero"];
           $output["colonia"] = $row["colonia"];
           $output["cp"] = $row["cp"];
           $output["ciudad"] = $row["ciudad"];
        }
        echo json_encode($output);
     }

     $datos = $paciente->get_dolor_x_id($_POST["idDolor"]);
     if(is_array($datos) == true and count($datos) > 0){
        foreach($datos as $row){
           $output["idDolor"] = $row["idDolor"];
           $output["Localizacion_idLocalizacion"] = $row["Localizacion_idLocalizacion"];
           $output["sintomas"] = $row["sintomas"];
        }
        echo json_encode($output);
 }

  break;

  case "eliminar":
     $paciente->delete_paciente($_POST["idPaciente"]);
     $paciente->delete_dolor($_POST["idDolor"]);
  break;
```

}
?>

```
<?php
class Paciente extends Conectar{
public function get_paciente(){ //Para que traiga todos los pacientes
    $conectar = parent::conexion();
    parent::set_names();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM paciente";
    $sql = $conectar->prepare($sql);
    $sql->execute();
    return $resultado = $sql->fetchAll();
}

public function get_paciente_x_id($idPaciente){ //"idPaciente" Mismo nombre que se tiene 
en la BD para llamar esa informacion
    $conectar = parent::conexion();
    parent::set_names();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM paciente WHERE idPaciente = ?";
    $sql = $conectar->prepare($sql);
    $sql->bindValue(1,$idPaciente);
    $sql->execute();
    return $resultado = $sql->fetchAll();
}

public function get_dolor_x_id($idDolor){ 
    $conectar = parent::conexion();
    parent::set_names();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dolor WHERE idDolor = ?";
    $sql = $conectar->prepare($sql);
    $sql->bindValue(1,$idDolor);
    $sql->execute();
    return $resultado = $sql->fetchAll();
}

public function delete_paciente($idPaciente){ 
    $conectar = parent::conexion();
    parent::set_names();
    $sql = "DELETE FROM paciente WHERE idPaciente = ?";
    $sql = $conectar->prepare($sql);
    $sql->bindValue(1,$idPaciente);
    $sql->execute();
    return $resultado = $sql->fetchAll();
}

public function delete_dolor($idDolor){ 
    $conectar = parent::conexion();
    parent::set_names();
    $sql = "DELETE FROM dolor WHERE idDolor = ?";
    $sql = $conectar->prepare($sql);
    $sql->bindValue(1,$idDolor);
    $sql->execute();
    return $resultado = $sql->fetchAll();
}

public function insert_paciente($nombrePac,$apellidoP,$apellidoM,$edad,$sexo,$ocupacion,$telefono,$calleNum,$colonia,$cp,$ciudad){ 
    $conectar = parent::conexion();
    parent::set_names();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO paciente (idPaciente, nombrePac, apellidoP, apellidoM, edad, Sexo_idSexo, Ocupacion_idOcupacion, telefono, calleNumero, colonia, cp, ciudad, fecha_crea, fecha_modi) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, now(),null)";
    $sql = $conectar->prepare($sql);
    $sql->bindValue(1,$nombrePac);
    $sql->bindValue(2,$apellidoP);
    $sql->bindValue(3,$apellidoM);
    $sql->bindValue(4,$edad);
    $sql->bindValue(5,$sexo);
    $sql->bindValue(6,$ocupacion);
    $sql->bindValue(7,$telefono);
    $sql->bindValue(8,$calleNum);
    $sql->bindValue(9,$colonia);
    $sql->bindValue(10,$cp);
    $sql->bindValue(11,$ciudad);
    $sql->execute();
    return $resultado = $sql->fetchAll();
}

public function insert_dolor($localizacion,$sintomas){ 
    $conectar = parent::conexion();
    parent::set_names();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `dolor` (`idDolor`, `Localizacion_idLocalizacion`, `sintomas`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?);";
    $sql = $conectar->prepare($sql);
    $sql->bindValue(1,$localizacion);
    $sql->bindValue(2,$sintomas);
    $sql->execute();
    return $resultado = $sql->fetchAll();
}

public function update_paciente($idPaciente,$nombrePac,$apellidoP,$apellidoM,$edad,$sexo,$ocupacion,$telefono,$calleNum,$colonia,$cp,$ciudad){ 
    $conectar = parent::conexion();
    parent::set_names();
    $sql = "UPDATE paciente SET nombrePac=?, apellidoP=?, apellidoM=?, edad=?, Sexo_idSexo=?,  Ocupacion_idOcupacion=?, telefono=?, calleNumero=?, colonia=?, cp=?, ciudad=?, fecha_modi=now() WHERE idPaciente=?";
    $sql = $conectar->prepare($sql);
    $sql->bindValue(1,$nombrePac);
    $sql->bindValue(2,$apellidoP);
    $sql->bindValue(3,$apellidoM);
    $sql->bindValue(4,$edad);
    $sql->bindValue(5,$sexo);
    $sql->bindValue(6,$ocupacion);
    $sql->bindValue(7,$telefono);
    $sql->bindValue(8,$calleNum);
    $sql->bindValue(9,$colonia);
    $sql->bindValue(10,$cp);
    $sql->bindValue(11,$ciudad);
    $sql->bindValue(12,$idPaciente);
    $sql->execute();
    return $resultado = $sql->fetchAll();
}

public function update_dolor($idDolor,$localizacion,$sintomas){ 
    $conectar = parent::conexion();
    parent::set_names();
    $sql = "UPDATE dolor SET Localizacion_idLocalizacion=?, sintomas=? WHERE idDolor=?";
    $sql = $conectar->prepare($sql);
    $sql->bindValue(1,$localizacion);
    $sql->bindValue(2,$sintomas);
    $sql->bindValue(3,$idDolor);
    $sql->execute();
    return $resultado = $sql->fetchAll();
}
```

}

?>

Comment: Tanto idDolor como idPaciente los pones en el formulario de este modo: `<input type="hidden" id="idDolor" name="idDolor">`pero sin ningún tipo de `value=` por lo tanto es probable que, aunque se envien por POST, estén vacios.

Comment: En value= que los que tendría que poner para que corra correctamente?

Comment: Bueno, mirándolo un poco mejor, el fallo no es solo ese... Creo que intentas aprovechar el formulario que estás usando para dar de alta un paciente para también editarlo después. Y sin embargo, no se aprecia la forma en que vas a rellenar sus datos, pues no tan solo idDolor e idPaciente se quedarían vacios, sino también todos los demás, y no te mostrarán nada (al menos con el código que has puesto en la pregunta).  Mi pregunta es... ¿como piensas rellenar esos campos de formulario cuando quieras editar algun paciente?  ¿has hecho algo sobre eso?